# Trying to generate WM_SEC.AUTH_SIGNATURE (Walmart.io)

Tags: java, walmart-api

Has anyone here successfully generated the Walmart.io API signature key?

I have tried to wrap my head around the java example but I am not having any luck of it as I have no Java experience.

I saw that there is a Python example here on StackOverFlow which would be interesting too, but it didn't work for me.

**The result I'm getting with Walmart Java code:**

consumerId: 36e010ef-0026-4713-9365-231323116afd

intimestamp: 1665872674888

Signature: null

**My code:**

```
package com.walmart.platform.common;

import java.io.ObjectStreamException;
import java.security.KeyRep;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class SignatureGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SignatureGenerator generator = new SignatureGenerator();

        String consumerId = "36e010ef-0026-4713-9365-231323116afd";
        String priviateKeyVersion = "2";
        String key = "jUiewb1+QbHl7ls+LoBO...O4j2NVjC2If4Z/r5FrykDVcO+nxb8G95X+zl";

        long intimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("consumerId: " + consumerId);
        System.out.println("intimestamp: " + intimestamp);

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("WM_CONSUMER.ID", consumerId);
        map.put("WM_CONSUMER.INTIMESTAMP", Long.toString(intimestamp));
        map.put("WM_SEC.KEY_VERSION", priviateKeyVersion);

        String[] array = canonicalize(map);

        String data = null;

        try {
            data = generator.generateSignature(key, array[1]);
        } catch(Exception e) { }
        System.out.println("Signature: " + data);
    }
    public String generateSignature(String key, String stringToSign) throws Exception {
        Signature signatureInstance = Signature.getInstance("SHA256WithRSA");

        ServiceKeyRep keyRep = new ServiceKeyRep(KeyRep.Type.PRIVATE, "RSA", "PKCS#8", Base64.decodeBase64(key));

        PrivateKey resolvedPrivateKey = (PrivateKey) keyRep.readResolve();

        signatureInstance.initSign(resolvedPrivateKey);

        byte[] bytesToSign = stringToSign.getBytes("UTF-8");
        signatureInstance.update(bytesToSign);
        byte[] signatureBytes = signatureInstance.sign();

        String signatureString = Base64.encodeBase64String(signatureBytes);

        return signatureString;
    }
    protected static String[] canonicalize(Map<String, String> headersToSign) {
        StringBuffer canonicalizedStrBuffer=new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer parameterNamesBuffer=new StringBuffer();
        Set<String> keySet=headersToSign.keySet();

        // Create sorted key set to enforce order on the key names
        SortedSet<String> sortedKeySet=new TreeSet<String>(keySet);
        for (String key :sortedKeySet) {
            Object val=headersToSign.get(key);
            parameterNamesBuffer.append(key.trim()).append(";");
            canonicalizedStrBuffer.append(val.toString().trim()).append("\n");
        }
        return new String[] {parameterNamesBuffer.toString(), canonicalizedStrBuffer.toString()};
    }

    class ServiceKeyRep extends KeyRep  {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -7213340660431987616L;
        public ServiceKeyRep(Type type, String algorithm, String format, byte[] encoded) {
            super(type, algorithm, format, encoded);
        }
        protected Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException {
            return super.readResolve();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't swallow exceptions unless you really know what you're doing, especially not when you're trying to debug a problem. Either catch it and _display_ it (most easily with e.printStackTrace()), or let it propagate out of main() and the JVM will display it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like private key you are using is not valid. Could you please regenerate public/private key pair and input valid private key. It will generate signature

Please follow the instructions listed here
https://walmart.io/docs/affiliate/quick-start-guide
https://walmart.io/key-tutorial

Regards,
Firdos
IO Support